# pass by ref to service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

can I pass a parameter to a service by ref in angular js?

for example:

```
var img = //image object from the view
MyService.ChangeSrc(img);
```

is it possible that the src can be changed in MyService function?

Comment: Yes you can pass by ref in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is no ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference) SO post is helpful). As far as I'm aware, Javascript doesn't support passing primitive types by reference.

Comment: Thanks, in the link they say that I can't pass primitive types by ref, only objects
so if I want to change the 'src' by ref, can I do something like that: img.src = new String();
?

Comment: I don't think so. Strings in Javascript are primitives. You could pass in the img object itself, though